# Access to Snowflake Internal Stage for Non Owner Role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, put, file-transfer, snowflake-pipe, movefile

I am putting data into Internal Table Stage and then use Copy command to load into Actual Table.
It is working fine with my ID since I am table owner ( my role).

Now, I am trying to run this process with a different user who has read and write access on table. I get below error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on table stage "stagename".

**is there a way to grant PUT access to other roles for internal table stage?**
I see this is possible for Names Stage but I do not see any documentation for Internal Table Stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use a named stage if you want to grant privileges:

> Note that a table stage is not a separate database object; rather, it
> is an implicit stage tied to the table itself. A table stage has no
> grantable privileges of its own. To stage files to a table stage, list
> the files, query them on the stage, or drop them, you must be the
> table owner (have the role with the OWNERSHIP privilege on the table).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-create-stage.html#table-stages